# do-while loop with switch statements-- infinity loop error

Tags: c++

I am just trying to create a simple "menu". Basically user can input their selection and when they enter 'E', it should exit the menu. I can't catch why its giving me an infinity loop-- i know its most likely my while loop(?). its all just hard-coded as im just trying to get the gist of it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char choice;
    int numOfCups;

    cout << "Hot Beverage Menu: \n";
    cout << "A: Coffee $1.00 \n";
    cout << "B: Tea $0.75 \n";
    cout << "C: Hot Chocolate: $1.25 \n";
    cout << "D: Cappuccino: $2.50 \n";
    cout << "E: Exit Menu \n";

    cout << "Please make a drink selection:";
    cin >> choice;
    do {
        switch(choice) {
            case 'A': cout << "You chose Coffee \n";
            cout << "How many cups would you like?";
            cin >> numOfCups;
            cout << "Your total will be: " << '$' << fixed << setprecision(2) << (1.00 * numOfCups) << endl;
            cout << "Please make another selection:";
            cin >> choice;
            break;

            case 'B': cout << "You chose Tea \n";
            cout << "How many cups would you like? \n";
            cin >> numOfCups;
            cout << "Your total will be: \n" << '$' << fixed << setprecision(2) << (0.75 * numOfCups) << endl;
            cout << "Please make another selection:";
            cin >> choice;
            break;

            case 'C': cout << "You chose Hot Chocolate \n";
            cout << "How many cups would you like? \n";
            cin >> numOfCups;
            cout << "Your total will be: \n" << '$' << fixed << setprecision(2) << (1.25 * numOfCups) << endl;
            cout << "Please make another selection:";
            cin >> choice;
            break;

            case 'D': cout << "You chose Cappuccino \n";
            cout << "How many cups would you like? \n";
            cin >> numOfCups;
            cout << "Your total will be: \n" << '$' << fixed << setprecision(2) << (2.50 * numOfCups) << endl;
            cout << "Please make another selection:";
            cin >> choice;
            break;

            case 'E': cout << "Exit Menu";
            break;

            default: cout << "Invalid input. Please make another selection.";
            break;
        } 
    } while (choice == 'E');
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move `cin >> choice;` down one line so that it's inside the loop, then you don't need `cin >> choice;` at the end of each switch case, and change `while (choice == 'E');` which tells it to only loop when you ask it to exit, to  `while (choice != 'E');`, which tells it to loop unless you ask it to exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop continues as long as the condition is true, and finishes when the condition is false. Instead of `while (choice == 'E')` you should have `while (choice != 'E')`.

Also, you should add `cin >> choice;` to the default condition, or you will have an infinite loop in that case.

Comment: Better yet, just put `cin >> choice'` once at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try `do ... while (choice != 'E');`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer seems incomplete to me. I recommend adding an explanation of what's wrong with the original code or how the proposed solution is an improvement.